# Request JIRA to get issue deatils based on "issue type" and "status" programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, jira, jira-rest-api

I have my request class like this:

```
public class SearchRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("jql")]
    public string JQL { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("startAt")]
    public int StartAt { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("maxResults")]
    public int MaxResults { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public List<string> Fields { get; set; }
    public SearchRequest()
    {
        Fields = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

I m making request like this:

```
      SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
        request.Fields = fields;
        request.JQL = jql;
        request.MaxResults = maxResult;
        request.StartAt = startAt;
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        string result = runQuery(JiraResource.search, data, "POST");
```

Actually I wanted to make search request based on "Issue type" and "Status", Can I make this in "SearchRequest" class property and append that in my request object?

I checked their tutorial, there is no REST API reference given for this. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The key in your class is the JQL property. In the Request's JQL parameter you can tell the Jira what are your filter criteria.

The latest Jira REST API can be found [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e1303) (which is actual the 6.4.11 version). This, if fact tells you very little about the filterint options, it just tells, that the Fields are used to narrow the results what you get back from the server.

So, about JQL you can find more info on the [Advanced Searching](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/advanced-searching-179442050.html) page in the Jira documentation. Here you find all the infos how you must build your JQL string to query for the issue type and status. I think your JQL will look like this:

```
issuetype = Bug and Status = Resolved
```

More close to your example

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest();
request.Fields = fields;
request.JQL = "issuetype = Bug and Status = Resolved";
...
```